# Giving Plot options defined outside of the Plot expression

Tags: plotting, options

How can I give `Plot` formating expressions on a separate line just like `ListPlot`?

When I use the following code with `ListPlot`, it produces a plot without any errors:

```
graphs = {ImageSize -> Full, Frame -> True};
ListPlot[Table[x, {x, 1, 2, .01}], graphs]
```

However, the same thing doesn't work for `Plot`:

```
graphs = {ImageSize -> Full, Frame -> True};
Plot[x, {x, 1, 2}, graphs]
```

Why? What is the simple notation change that I need to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
Plot[x, {x, 1, 2}, Evaluate@graphs]
```

Why?

The reason `Plot[x, {x, 1, 2}, graphs]` doesn't work and `ListPlot[Table[x, {x, 1, 2, .01}], graphs]`does is that `Plot` has attribute [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html) (*"all arguments (..) maintained in an unevaluated form"*)

```
Attributes[Plot]
```

> {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected}

whereas `ListPlot` doesn't:

```
Attributes[ListPlot]
```

> {Protected, ReadProtected}

Comment: Alternatively, you can inject `graph` using `With` as in m_goldberg's answer or using `Plot[x, {x, 1, 2}, #] &@graphs`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `With` because it makes the needed substitution before `Plot` sees any of its arguments.

```
options = {ImageSize -> Full, Frame -> True};
With[{opts = options}, Plot[x, {x, 1, 2}, opts]
```

[image: plot]